# How to reduce WCF soap message size to save bandwidth?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, bandwidth

I've written a `MessageSizeInspector` class  to inspect the size of the messages the service receives from the client. Here is what it looks like:

```
//the actual implementation logs more!
//but in this question, my only concerns is request.ToString()
public sealed class MessageSizeInspector : 
            BehaviorExtensionElement,   //to enable it to be used in config
            IDispatchMessageInspector,  //service-side inspector
            IEndpointBehavior           //so we can apply it on endpoint
{
   if (request != null )
   {
      Logger.Verbose("Message = {0}\n", request.ToString()));
   }       
   //more  
}
```

And it logs message of this format:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:8961/EngineService</To>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IEngineService/GetMousePatternID</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetMousePatternID xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <args>
        <accelerator xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Runaware.Insight.EngineService" />
        <accessKey xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Runaware.Insight.EngineService" />
        <controlId xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Runaware.Insight.EngineService">66222</controlId>

        <!--- deleted the rest to avoid verbosity -->

      </args>
    </GetMousePatternID>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you can see the actual message is *tiny*, but the XML elements and namespaces make it *too huge*. Namespaces, in particular, are too big in comparison to the actual message.

My question is : how can we reduce the size of the *soap* messages? As the `xmlns` are same for all elements, the WCF could optimize this but it doesn't. Can we make it use shorter namespace of our choice? There are few elements such as `accelerator` and `accessKey` which do not even have any value (as you can see by scrolling right), but they're still there! Can we make WCF to omit them and assume their values `null` (or default value) on the service side?

In short, anything we can do to save bandwidth?

I'm assuming that the above message is what comes the client, exactly in the same format, with same XML elements and namespaces.

The server is written in C# and WCF, and the client is written in C++ using [Windows Web Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The service and client both written by me. So I've full control over them. If required, I may change it to save bandwidth!

Comment: How much control do you have over the WCF services? Is there any chance you can change to `WebAPI` instead as this sends much less data.

Comment: @Dommer: I've full control. The services and client both written by me.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the anwsers that the others already said (eg: WCF compressing)...

Try setting Name and Namespaces on DataContracts, DataMembers as well as ServiceContracts.

Example:

```
 [DataContract(Name = "a", Namespace = "")]
 class Person
 {
     [DataMember(Name = "a")]
     public string FullName;
     [DataMember(Name = "b)]
     public int Age;
 }
```

This will make Person to be called as "a" from namespace "" and the property FullName to be called as "a", making the XML shorter like:

> ```
> <a> -- Represents the Person class
>     <a>Name of the person</a> -- Represents the FullName property
>     <b>38</b>
> </a>
> ```

Properties and classes must have different "short" names from DataContract and DataMembers.

Reference: https://bkiener.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/optimize-data-contracts-for-better-wcf-performance/

Comment: Wow. This is a big help. It's so obvious but hadn't occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, well my first approach would be to use [WCF Compression](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCF-Compression-Example-9ffab49c). I can only give you the link, because I've no experience with it. But I assume, that it would be a pretty good improvement.

Question is, do you have influence on the client. Because its configuration must also be edited.

Edit: Question is answered in one of your comments. :o)

Comment: note: if you're using .NET 4 and above the 'workaround' in this article is no longer needed and you can directly enable compression in IIS

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SOAP and the problem many people meet with ignorance. XML is nice, SOAP too, but there IS an overhead of having a text based expressive system. And the bandwidth hit is hugh, especially for small messages.

THere is not a lot you can do - outside compression in IIS and then dropping soap / xml and go web api with JSON. The web servviec / soap standard is quite - hm - explicit and a standard. Bypassing it (drop requirement, use something else) is the only way to really deal with it.

Comment: Actually, Json can be worse. Neither JSON, nor XML are optimized. They are both designed for human consumption. Binary is a much better serialization method, but unfortunately, WCF's binary DataContractSerializer suffers from the same serialization problems as SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have full control over everything, why not change to use [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) instead?

Take a look at this question before you make your final decision: [Do I need WCF if I can use ASP.net Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532967/do-i-need-wcf-if-i-can-use-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: What is the advantage of WebAPI? Is it for client-side or service-side? Please post some details *pertaining* to the question.

Comment: My whole server-side implementation uses WCF already. It would cost too much to change it now.